# Cocoapods podspec preserve_paths

Tags: cocoapods

[Podspec documentation](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/wiki/The-podspec-format) says preserve_path is for "Any file that should not be cleaned (CocoaPods cleans all files by default)."

What does it mean by "clean"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

'Clean' means that it will delete the files that should be 'cleaned'

For example if you have a directory with a few files

- source.h
- source.m
- readme.md
- other.txt

If you just specify the source files as `*.{h,m}` then those will be added to the project and readme.md and other.txt will be removed. If you for some reason wanted the user to be able to access one of those files you would add it to the `preserve_paths` so it would not get delete.